# Select Object change selected value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Working on a web app which includes a shift management page.

In that page a table will be drawn with values which can be selected.
The calendar will be redrawn each time a user selects a different date range.
Because the date range is what is required for the database.

What I am struggling is how the change the select values based on the data which is being received

I have a function which returns a new Map object

```
function builtSelect(data){
    /*
        qysh m vinj te dhenat

        return result dmth 
        user -> 7 vlera te select sipas arrays
        $(document).ready(function() {
                    $("#gate option[value='Gateway 2']").prop('selected', true);
                     // you need to specify id of combo to set right combo, if more than one combo
        });
        useri -> te gjitha shiftat
        foreach( var [key,value] of data){

        var s = $('<select/>');
        var o = [1, 2, 3];
        for (var i in o) {
            s.append($('<option/>').html(o[i]));
        }
            $('body').append(s);

        }
        okay 
        nihere krijoje 
        select objectin masanej veq e thirr

    */
    var builtShifts = [];
    var options = ["volvo","saab","mercedes","audi"];
    var select = $('<select>');
    options.forEach(function(i){
        select.append($("<option>").attr('value',i).text(i))
    });
    for(var [key,value] of data){
        sel = new Map()
        sel.set(key,[])
        $.each(value,function(c,i){
                sc = select.clone();
                sel.get(key).push(sc);

        })
        builtShifts.push(sel);

    }
    return builtShifts;

}
```

Trying to change the selected based on the data array:

```
$(sc).each(function(){
                        if($(this).text() == String(i[0])){
                            $(this).attr("selected","selected")
                        }
                    })
```

The selected value is there, however when trying to make the table all of these selects have a selection of "Volvo" which in some cases it shouldn't.

What I am trying to achieve is:

```
<select>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="vw">VW</option>
  <option value="audi" selected>Audi</option>
</select>
```

Each selected would change based on the value of i[0]

Comment: $(this).val() instead of $(this).text()

Comment: What is `sc`?  Where does the `i` variable come from?

Comment: sc is a clone of the select object, i the data I need